# How to get an image with full clarity?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage, android-bitmap

I tried loading images from sdcard camera folder,after loading I created bitmap by using scaled bitmap,in that I want to show only some portions of image so I tried using createBitmap() to create a new bitmap,but it is still getting blurred, how can i solve this problem?

```
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {

                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                itemList.add(path);


                if (myBitmap != null) {
                    myBitmap = null;
                }

                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                System.out.println("thumbnails1 width: " + myBitmap.getWidth());
                System.out.println("thumbnails1 height: " + myBitmap.getHeight());
                myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 150, 150, false);

                ExifInterface exif;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    String orientString = exif
                            .getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

                    int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer
                            .parseInt(orientString)
                            : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                    int rotationAngle = 0;

                    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                        System.out.println("photopotart");
                        rotationAngle = 90;

                        System.out.println("myBitmap" + myBitmap.getWidth());
                        System.out.println("myBitmap" + myBitmap.getHeight());

                         myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 150, 150,
                         false);



                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(90);
                        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0,
                                150, 150, matrix,
                                true);

                        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, 150, 100 );

                    myBitmap = highlightImage(myBitmap);

                        photsList.add(myBitmap);
                    }

                    else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                        System.out.println("180 angle");
                        rotationAngle = 180;

                    } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                        System.out.println("other 270");
                        rotationAngle = 270;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("photolandscape");
                    myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 150, 150,
                                false);


                        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 30, 0, 120, 150);



                        photsList.add(myBitmap);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }








            }
        }
```

My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method for decoding your file path.

```
 public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

    int scale = 2;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2); // this bmp object of Bitmap is global and you can set it to your ImageView.
    }
```

Now you can call this function replace with this one

```
   myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

to

```
   decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

You can set your scale variable according to your requirement that you can get your image with very good clarity.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply after using this little bit better compare to previous one,but problem occuring is some shadow is occuping on photos

Comment: you can increase REQUIRED_SIZE  and scale variable according to your requirement. So you can get better output.

Comment: present i am using s3 mini and nexus4 then howmuch  i can  give to REQUIRED_SIZE

Comment: you can give it 2048 and scale to 3.

Comment: can i know the use of scale and required size?

Comment: REQUIRED_SIZE  means if your image is very high means in MB then this will be used and scale means according to required size it can be scaled that image which will be the power of 2.

Comment: but i am giving the 2048 and scale is 3,but no use,images are not getting full clarity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49643/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-user3114723)